# Put data from a file into arrays space by space?

Tags: c, file, text

I have a text file with 4 different data points: Name, age, state, gender

in the text file it generally looks like this:

```
Scott 22 California M
Anna 40 Florida F
```

and so on and so on. Is there a simple way to put them into four different arrays? I thought `fscanf` would do the trick but it takes the whole line.

Comment: No "John Doe"? Nobody from "Rhode Island"? Read line-by-line with `fgets()` then parse the line for each part.

Comment: If your fields are whitespace-separated, and you can rely on them being nonempty and free from internal whitespace, without excess fields, then yes, `fscanf` can do this for you.  It's unclear what you tried that made you think otherwise.

Comment: Alternatively, if your fields are fixed-width then `fscanf()` can do it, but with a different format.

Comment: You can read multiple variables with one call to `fscanf()`

Comment: "Is there a simple way to put them into four different arrays?" No, not in C

Comment: @JohnBollinger You were right about `fscanf`. I just rewrote it and now it prints line by line. I am not sure what I was doing before, but I appreciate the assistance regardless!